# Issue with Python's requests library - ConnectionError

Tags: python, flask

I'm facing a `ConnectionError` when using the Python `requests` library to make API calls. I've checked my internet connection, and the API endpoint seems to be up.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.example.com/data'

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

I've tried troubleshooting this but haven't been successful. Any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The remote host isn't responding. Unless you are using the wrong URL, there's nothing to debug on your end: it's an issue on their end. How are you checking the end point, in  a web browser?

Comment: @thehungrycub why on Earth did you make that edit? That's not at all how code formatting works

Comment: facing a similar issue with the request library, my api calls running infinitely in my loop, yesterday it was working fine

Comment: Thanks, @chepner, for the quick response. It seems you were right; the issue was with the server. It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the problem, I suggest you try the following (on the same computer, i.e. your workstation):

1. Open the URL using your browser. If it's just a GET request, it should be easy to do. If you don't get a response, the problem is unrelated to Python's `requests`.
2. If you do get a response, try the same request using the command-line tool `curl` (or `wget`, Postman, or any other tool). If you get no response, the website might be vetting requests by looking at the request headers, and rejecting those that seem to come from automations. If so, you'll need to figure out what the measures are so you can bypass them ... or respect their wishes and usage terms and stay away.
3. If curl works but `requests` still doesn't, then the problem might be with your code and you should provide a less simplified version so we can help you.